# R: Create column with tags from exported Facebook .csv data

Tags: facebook, r, data-analysis

I am analyzing my Facebook page's posts to see what kind of posts attract the most people. So I want to create columns with the tags used. Here's an example of how the data export would look like:

```
Post              Likes
Blah   #a          10
Blah Blah #b       12
Blah Bleh #a       10
Bleh   #b           9
Bleh Blah #a #b    15
```

I want to create this:

```
Post              Likes   tags
Blah   #a          10      #a
Blah Blah #b       12      #b
Blah Bleh #a       10      #a
Bleh   #b           9      #b
Bleh Blah #a #b    15      #a #b
Bleh #b Blah #a    14      #a #b
```

Is this possible? I thought of using grep1 to check for posts with "#" inside, but I'm stuck at what to do next.

Comment: It is hard to use your data example. Please use `dput` to reproduce your data next time. Also it is better to show the code that you have tried even it doesn't work.

Comment: Two points to remember. 1) When importing data into R the hash-character is special by default and you need to use comment.char=FALSE to suppress that behavior. 2) you have not offered a realistic example that had typical hashtags that used multiple characters so do not have any answers that will succeed with real tweets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `gregexpr` for example to find the desired pattern and `regmatches` to extract it:

```
txt = c('Bleh Blah #a #b','Blah Bleh #a')
regmatches(txt,gregexpr('#[a-z]',txt))   ## I assume a tag is # followed by lower letter 
[[1]]
[1] "#a" "#b"

[[2]]
[1] "#a"
```

using alexis example, you write something like this:

```
DF$tag <- regmatches(DF$Post,gregexpr('#[a-z]',DF$Post)
```

**edit** in case tag is someething like #hi (more than one letter):

```
txt = c('Bleh Blah #hi allo #b','Blah Bleh #a')
regmatches(txt,gregexpr('#[a-z]+',txt))

[1]]
[1] "#hi" "#b" 

[[2]]
[1] "#a"
```

Comment: I, also, tried at first to incorporate `gregexpr` but couldn't set it up to return a tag like `#hi!`. Have you got any idea on how to syntax the regular expression in case the tags aren't just `#a`?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work:

```
#random data
DF <- data.frame(Post = c("asd wer #a", "dfg #b gg", 
                          "wer #c qwe qweeee #a #b", "asd asd, ioi #a #c"),
                 Likes = c(sample(1:50, 4)), stringsAsFactors = F)

#find tags
Tags <- lapply(DF$Post, function(x) { spl <- unlist(strsplit(x, " ")) ; 
                                      paste(spl[grep("#", spl)], collapse = ",") })

DF$Tags <- Tags

> DF
                     Post Likes     Tags
1              asd wer #a     9       #a
2               dfg #b gg    10       #b
3 wer #c qwe qweeee #a #b    46 #c,#a,#b
4      asd asd, ioi #a #c    31    #a,#c
```